# Error en consola al enviar datos del formulario mediante Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Amigos por favor necesito ayuda no se porque ajax no me trae el resultado de la petición cuando envio datos de mi formulario. Si alguien por lo menos me explicara cual es mi error y de que se trata?. Gracias.

Lo que yo se, es que cuando envío mis datos al .php mediante ajax inserto al asuario y efectivamente lo hace pero en mi condición donde valida si se ejecuto la consulta esta mi variable que aguarda el resultado que debo llevar al html, pero no pasa nada. No me muestra el alert e igual me muestra ese error cuando recargo en otra página:

Mi código:

```
document.getElementById("enviar").onclick = function() {
    RegistrarUsuario();
};

String.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
  return (this.length === 0 || !this.trim());
};



     function RegistrarUsuario(){
    var comprobar = false;
    //Datos proporcionado por el usuario
    js_matricula =$("#matricula_1").val();
    js_nombre =$("#nombre_1").val();
    js_apellido_pa =$("#apellido_pa_1").val();
    js_apellido_ma =$("#apellido_ma_1").val();
    js_carrera = $('#id_carrera').val();

var arreglo = new Array(js_matricula, js_nombre,js_apellido_pa,js_apellido_ma);
for(var i=0; i<arreglo.length; i++){
    if(arreglo[i].isEmpty()){
         comprobar = true;
         break;
    }
}

if(comprobar){
    alert("Por favor, no deje ningun campo sin texto.");
    return;
}

var request = $.ajax({
  url: "Verificacion/Validar_Entrada.php",
  method: "POST",
  data:{ matricula:js_matricula, nombre:js_nombre, apellido_pa:js_apellido_pa, apellido_ma:js_apellido_ma, id_carrera: js_carrera},
  dataType:"jsonp",
  jsonp:"jsoncallback",
  crossDomain: true,
  cache: false
});

request.done(function( data ) {
          if(data.estado=="exito"){
              alert("Muy bien");
          }else{
              alert("Algo inesperado a ocurrido, por favor intentelo más tarde.");
          }
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
alert( "Error en la petición: " + textStatus );
});

return false;
 }
```

Mi .php

```
    <?php

  header("Content-type: application/json");


    $matricula = $_GET['matricula'];
    $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
    $apellido_pa = $_GET['apellido_pa'];
    $apellido_ma = $_GET['apellido_ma'];
    $id_carrera = $_GET['id_carrera'];
    $id_carrera =  (!empty($id_carrera))  ?  $id_carrera  : NULL ;



    $datos = array();

    $nombre = trim($nombre , " ");
    $apellido_pa = trim($apellido_pa , " ");
    $apellido_ma = trim($apellido_ma , " ");

    //Deja solo un espacio en blanco entre palabras
    $nombre  = preg_replace( "([ ]+)"," ",$nombre);
    $apellido_pa  = preg_replace( "([ ]+)"," ",$apellido_pa);
    $apellido_ma  = preg_replace( "([ ]+)"," ",$apellido_ma);



    include_once('Conexion/Abrir_Conexion.php');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO alumno (matricula, nombre, apellido_pa, apellido_ma, id_carrera) 
             VALUES 
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $sentencia=$conexion->prepare($sql);
    $sentencia->bind_param("isssi", $matricula, $nombre, $apellido_pa, $apellido_ma, $id_carrera);

    if($sentencia->execute()){
        $datos["estado"] = "exito"; 
    }else{
        $datos["estado"] = "error";
    }

    $sentencia->close();
    $conexion->close();

    $resultadoJson = json_encode($datos);
    echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $resultadoJson . ');';
```

Amigos realice cambios que ustedes me sugerieron pero ahora no me manda el error no se si es el dataType, porque aun así no me manda el alert(de que si esta bien o mal ni el error me arroja);  solo inserta registros recarga la página y de nuevo otra vez.  Que esta pasando ???

Comment: Podrías utilizar las herramientras de desarrollo de firefox o chrome y ver en "Red" si la petición que haces via ajax, devuelve algo en la respuesta? En caso afirmativo, está devolviendo el estado?

Comment: Asi de primeras estas enviando los parametros por `POST` y recogiendolos por `GET`

Comment: Parece que el error que compartes no está en el código de la pregunta sino en otra parte completamente diferente. ¿Estás seguro de que ese es el error que recibes por el ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es tanto la divergencia entre GET/POST. Si mal no recuerdo, alguna vez he probado a enviar por `POST` y leer por `GET` y no ha habido problema en mostrar los datos. Aún así, conviene ser coherentes: si es POST que se POST en todo.

<s>**El problema principal es que, dado que estás usando `JSONP`  en la respuesta, tu url tiene que terminar así: `&callback=?`, de lo contrario no te va a funcionar.**</s>

Haciendo una prueba en mi servidor, lo he hecho funcionar haciendo lo siguiente:

**En Javascript:**

- Quitando `jsonp:"jsoncallback",`

**En PHP:**

- Usando `GET` (aunque la petición desde el cliente sea `POST`), y poniendo la clave `callback` en el `GET`. Si pongo otra cosa que no sea `callback` no funciona.

Aquí te dejo el código. Pondré también `preventDefault` para evitar que la página se refresque y todo el bloque de código dentro de `function` para asegurarnos que el DOM está listo antes de lanzar la petición.

El código, está adaptado a las recomendaciones de jQuery: `type` es para versiones antiguas de jQuery, se recomienda usar `method` en su lugar.

También `success` es obsoleto desde jQuery 3, se recomienda el uso de `done` y también implementar al menos `fail` para informar cuando la petición falle y no dejar al usuario esperando creyendo que la petición se está procesando. jQuery recomiendo crear la petición Ajax en una variable y luego añadirle las funciones `done`, `fail` y, eventalmente `always`, `complete`. Esta es una forma de aprovechar la estructura similar a `Promises` que implementa jQuery en las peticiones Ajax.

Para más detalles sobre todo lo dicho anteriormente [puedes consultar la documentación](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
$(function() {
    $("#enviar").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        RegistrarUsuario();
    });

    String.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
        return (this.length === 0 || !this.trim());
    };

    function RegistrarUsuario() {
        var request=$.ajax({
                        url: "Verificacion/Validar_Entrada.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        data:{ matricula:js_matricula, nombre:js_nombre, apellido_pa:js_apellido_pa, apellido_ma:js_apellido_ma, id_carrera: js_carrera},
                        dataType:"jsonp",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        cache: false
        });

        request.done(function( data ) {
                        if(data.estado=="exito"){
                            alert("Muy bien");
                        }else{
                            alert("Algo inesperado a ocurrido, por favor intentelo más tarde.");
                        }
        });

        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
          alert( "Error en la petición: " + textStatus );
        });

        /*Opcional: Lo puedes usar para mostrar algo cuando termine la petición*/
        request.complete(function() {
                console.log("fin");
        });

        }
});
```

No sé exactamente que significa el `return false;`  al final del código. Lo cierto es que con esta estructura tú puedes implementar un `request.completed` (ver la documentación en el enlace de más arriba, esta parte se explica al final) y poner allí lo que quieras, cuando el ciclo de la petición haya terminado.

---

### PHP

El código PHP es correcto. Solamente tienes que poner `callback` en el `GET` y quizá convendría poner un header para indicar el tipo de contenido y la codificación, antes de imprimir la salida:

```
//... todo lo anterior igual
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $resultadoJson . ');';
```

> **NOTA:**
>
> La peticiones usando JSONP  suelen usarse cuando hay orígenes
>   diferentes (desde un dominio se piden datos a otro dominio distinto).
>   Si tu petición es dentro del mismo dominio quizá lo más simple sea
>   hacer una petición normal, sin usar `callbacks`.

Comment: Amigo gracias por responder me has ayudado mucho pero no encuentro mi error segui tu recomendcion agrege: &callback=? y no pasa nada ni error, ni insercion de registro solo recarga la pagina y ya.  Y cuando quito eso, lo dejo normal me inserta pero no me manda el error.

Comment: A lo mejor omitiste algún pequeño detalle. Si se recarga la página es necesario revisar que hayas puesto `preventDefault` generalmente al inicio del código que inicia la petición Ajax... Si quieres haz una edición de la pregunta para ver cómo quedó el código. Como indica la documentación, no es posible obtener los datos si usas JSONP y no pones `callback`. Debe faltar una mínima cosa en tu código, pero sin verlo completo es imposible saber qué es.

Comment: Amigo mi código que veras es el que tengo actualmente no he modificado nada y me inserta pero no me manda error y tampoco me muestra los alert

Comment: @DiegosSánchez tienes que ponerle `preventDefault` para que no te recargue la página: `document.getElementById("enviar").onclick = function(event) { event.preventDefault();
    RegistrarUsuario();
};`   Y... le quitas el `return false;`  que hay al final del código. En la parte del done le puedes poner un console.log para ver si te trae datos: `request.done(function( data ) {  console.log(data);  ` para verlo debes inspeccionar la consola, supongo que sabrás cómo hacerlo. Ah, y pon `POST` no `GET`  aquí: `echo $_POST['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $resultadoJson . ');';`

Comment: @DiegosSánchez revisa el código editado. He hecho una prueba en mi dominio y esa fue la forma en que lo hice funcionar. Básicamente quitando el atributo `jsonp` de la petición Ajax y en la clave del `GET` poniendo `callback`. Como dato curioso, si desde el servidor yo ponía `POST` no me funciona, me funciona sólo con `GET` aunque en Ajax el método sea `POST`. He probado el código como está ahora en la respuesta y me funciona.

Comment: Amigo si funciono pero solo tome una parte del código busque otra forma y me funciona Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

este es tu error pana no puedes enviar parametros por post y luego recivirlos con get o te decides por **post** o por **get**, yo te recomiendo post siempre sera mas seguro que get

```
$.ajax({
              type: "POST", //en mi la mayoria de vecez uso post 
              url: "Verificacion/Validar_Entrada.php",
              data:{ matricula:js_matricula, nombre:js_nombre, apellido_pa:js_apellido_pa, apellido_ma:js_apellido_ma, id_carrera: js_carrera},
              dataType:"jsonp",
              jsonp:"jsoncallback",
              crossDomain: true,
              cache: false,
              success: function(data){
                if(data.estado=="exito"){
                    alert("Muy bien");
                }else{
                    alert("Algo inesperado a ocurrido, por favor intentelo más tarde.");
                }
              }
});
//Este return es de mi funcion
      return false;
```

**ASI quedaria tu php**

```
 $matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido_pa = $_POST['apellido_pa'];
        $apellido_ma = $_POST['apellido_ma'];
        $id_carrera = $_POST['id_carrera'];

        $id_carrera =  (!empty($id_carrera))  ?  $id_carrera  : NULL ;


    $datos = array();

        $nombre = trim($nombre , " ");
        $apellido_pa = trim($apellido_pa , " ");
        $apellido_ma = trim($apellido_ma , " ");

        //Deja solo un espacio en blanco entre palabras
        $nombre  = preg_replace( "([ ]+)"," ",$nombre);
        $apellido_pa  = preg_replace( "([ ]+)"," ",$apellido_pa);
        $apellido_ma  = preg_replace( "([ ]+)"," ",$apellido_ma);

    include_once('Conexion/Abrir_Conexion.php');

        $sql = "INSERT INTO alumno (matricula, nombre, apellido_pa, apellido_ma, id_carrera) 
                 VALUES 
                (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        $sentencia=$conexion->prepare($sql);
        $sentencia->bind_param("isssi", $matricula, $nombre, $apellido_pa, $apellido_ma, $id_carrera);

        if($sentencia->execute()){


            $datos["estado"] = "exito";
        }else{
            $datos["estado"] = "error";
        }

        $sentencia->close();
        $conexion->close();
        $resultadoJson = json_encode($datos);
        echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $resultadoJson . ');';
```